# Regex working in regexpal but not in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple regex which searches a sentence to see if it contains the word of|for|in|at and here is my regex that is almost working in regexpal:

[^A-Za-z]of|for|in|at[^A-Za-z]

I run it on following setences:

```
show me the weather of seattle
show me the weather in seattle
show me the weather for seattle
show me the weather at seattle
```

and here are results:

[image]

When I use it in my Java code it doesnt works at all. In regexpal too is shows space with for and at which I defined at start and end. Can someone please tell what is wrong with my regex and how to search for one of many words in a sentence

I always get else condition in my java which means it is not matching regex. Here is my java code:

```
public class Regex 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "show me the weather in seattle";

    if(str.matches("[^A-Za-z]of|for|in|at[^A-Za-z]")){
        System.out.println("Yayyy!!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("OMG now what to do");
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: `matches` checks the string is completely. It is not looking for a match. try add `.*` at start and end regexp

Comment: also, your "space" is only in front of "of" and after "at".  use `[^A-Za-z](of|for|in|at)[^A-Za-z]` or, better, `\\W(of|for|in|at)\\W`

Comment: @turbanoff I tried .* but problem is it even matches "show me the weather seattle" when I remove "at" because at is present in weather and seattle. I need independent occurance of any word hence I used [^A-Za-z]

Comment: @andrewcooke Your code works perfectly in regexcode but not in java. Do I need to append something in str.matches(regex) to make it work for java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work `.*[^A-Za-z](of|for|in|at)[^A-Za-z].*` ?. Ofcourse you will need to do extra to check for the boundary cases where of|for|in|at is either the start or the end of the word.

Comment: Thanks. It works. In my statements those words will appear between the statements only. Regards

Comment: You shouldn't need the `.*` at all.  The regular expression is being bound to a non letter before and after any one of the words in the set; adding `.*` is completely unnecessary and pointless.

Comment: @EliSand You didn't understand that the `mathes` method checks whether the full string is matched by the regex right ? It is like that, so your assumption works only when there is no other "letter" in the string before and after the match. So here it works like - `May be some characters, whatever`,`then a non letter`,`then what I am looking for`,`then a non letter`,`then may be some more characters,whatever` :-)

Comment: @EliSand And also before saying un-necessary and pointless you should come with a different working answer, do you have any ?

Comment: I retract my comment - I assumed that no-one would ever create a function that implicitly implies ^ and $ on a regex.  It saves two characters and prevents functionality... alas I didn't write Java.  My apologies on the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^A-Za-z](?:of|for|in|at)[^A-Za-z]
```

You want to group the "or" matches, otherwise it thinks you mean:

```
[^A-Za-z]of  OR  for  OR  in  OR  at[^A-Za-z]
```

which is very likely not what you want.

Comment: Pro-tip: the `?:` part inside the `()` makes the match just a group but not usable as a match entity or whatever the technical mumbo jumbo description is.

Comment: It works regex pal but not in java. In Java my code again goes to else case, do I need to append something to it to call in str.matches(). And yes I want occurence of 1 of or for or in or at. I want it to be able to see whether user has any of [of|for|in|at] in his statements

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're actually trying to achieve with your regular expression, you should use `\b(of|for|in|at)\b`.  Also, does `.matches()` return true/false or some condition that can be tested as such?